# access to a document with some questions for a short amount of time

Tags: document-management, remote-access

I am hiring for my team and would like to give access to a document with some questions for a short amount of time after they either access the document or after logging in on a platform.

So the flow would be:

1. send email with link to document to candidate
2. candidate opens the link whenever he has time to do the test
3. as soon as the link is accessed, a timer starts counting down
4. a file needs to be uploaded with the answers to the question before the timer is over, once is over no upload will be allowed.

I've seen this somewhere before but don't really remember where or the platform they were using.